# Maven multi-module +tomcat in eclipse Jrebel dont have console

Tags: maven, tomcat, jrebel

I use maven multi-module project like this:

```
com.user.business  (this is for db ORM api)

com.user.member   

com.user.platform; com.user.playground
```

Уvery time I change the logic in ORM which means 'com.user.business' 
I need to maven install it first.
And my other project will call this project API, so I need to compile it.

I use Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) and download Jrebel plugin 
JRebel works in debug. I `sysout` and success, but sometimes it will not print success.

Do I need to set some config for JRebel ?

Maven project pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I use tomcat:run to run the project, I can't find any **web.xml** and config 
for Tomcat.

I need to know why JRebel deploy success. Our maven server is using Nexus,

I need to know how to let my JRebel console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to set some config for JRebel ?

Make sure that all modules have JRebel enabled for them (**Help** > **JRebel** > **Configuration** > *Projects*), this will generate a *rebel.xml* configuration file that is used to map the actual class files to their respective build directories.

You shouldn't need a full **mvn install** after changing the source, just make sure that the changed class is recompiled in the build directory and JRebel will reload it into the running JVM.

Comment: Thank you to reply me: YES,My rebel.xml was there,and I it work sometime when I change the java. But when jrebel deploy success I cant get any message,so I use debug and system.out to know is jrebel work? when I change the ORM project (the other project call this method),It need to rebuild,but sometime dosent need to rebuild(jrebel will do it for me). 
So I need to know 
How can I log when jrebel  deploy my maven multi-module in Eclipse console.
rebel.xml:
<classpath>
<dir name="D:/gitbranch/lgame-business/target/classes">
</dir>
</classpath>

Comment: This is my jrebel plugin in Eclipse setting,in this pic
https://imgur.com/tAhSZY8
In the path C:\Users\user\.jrebel\jrebel.log ,I cant find the file.
I dont know how to fix my Eclipse ,help me guys!